# GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync Invalid Token

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

We have a problem after creating a new user on the generate password reset. When validating we receive invalid token.
We have the following code to generate the password reset token.

```
var user = await _userManagerWrapper.FindByIdAsync(id);
var code = await _userManagerWrapper.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
```

This token is then put in a mail en send to the user. To reset the password we use the following code.

```
var result = await _userManagerWrapper.ResetPasswordAsync(user, code, viewModel.Password);
```

A few things about the process. After the creation of a user their is still 2 other view to set claims for the user. After this the token is generated and mailed to the user.

Things I have tried.

1. Visit the edit user screen. This makes the token **valid**.
2. Validate the token instant after creation. This makes the token **valid**.
3. Have a delay of 80 seconds after retrieving the user and before the generation. This times out the request but the token is **valid**.
4. Have a delay of 60 seconds after retrieving the user and before the generation. This times out the request and the token is **invalid**.
5. Wait more then 5 minutes after user creation before letting it send. The token is **invalid**
6. Send the token 2 times. This first token is **invalid**. The second token is **Valid**

Comment: Try to use base 64 url to encode the token, then base 64 url to decode, install Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;